# Converting a String of input into Inches

Tags: c#

What I would like to do is to take input string, in architectural format and convert it to a double in inches.
For example:

```
Input: (String)    Output: (Double)

1'-2"              14    
1'-2 1/2"          14.5    
1'2 3/16"          14.1875    
1'                 12    
12                 12    
12"                12    
1'0.5              12.5    
1'0.5"             12.5    
1'-0.5             12.5    
1'-0.5"            12.5
```

I know I would need to iterate through every character in the string and test a bunch of cases but I did not know if there was some built in function within c# or within some other resource that could do this for me and not make me re-invent the wheel.

Comment: C# doesnt have thing like that, you need to parse by yourself and try out...

Comment: Indeed, there is no function that will do all of that for you and recommendations to other resources are off topic for this site.

Comment: I've never seen it written as `1'-2"` Anything you find to do it for you might return you `10"`.

Comment: Why does the input mix fractions and decimals? Why is there sometimes a dash and sometimes not? I'd ask whoever produced the data to fix it first.

Comment: I am wanting to make the textbox and input as flexible as possible and not restrict the user to entering everything specifically in inches or feet. I also don't want to limit the user to enter it a specific way.

Comment: I know this comment is not very productive, but looking at your post makes me love the metric system...

Answer (score 1):

Regex for the win!

Okay, if you're new to Regex, it's basically a way of parsing strings.  So, realistically, what does your input consist of?

At a high level, you've got one of these three possibilities:

1. Composite: Number, followed by ', followed by either a - or space,
   followed by a number, and optionally ending with a "
2. Feet Only: Number, followed by a '
3. Inches Only: Number, optionally followed by a "

And those 'Number's?

Possibilities:

- 1+ digits (aka, "23")
- 1+ digits, a '.', and 1+ digits (aka, "32.43")
- 1+ digits, a space, 1+ digits, a slash, and 1+ digits (aka, "32
  13/16")
- 1+ digits, a slash, and 1+ digits (aka, "13/16")

Okay, so first up, we need a regex for one of your "numbers":

```
\d+|\d+.\d+|\d+ \d+\/\d+|\d+\/\d+
```

(Looks complicated, but see these two pages for reference: http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html and https://regex101.com/)

Now, just so our regex'es don't get *too* complicated, you could do something like this:

```
string regexSnippetForNumber = @"\d+|\d+.\d+|\d+ \d+\/\d+|\d+\/\d+";
string regexForComposite = 
    "^(" + regexSnippetForNumber + ")'[ -]" + 
    "(" + regexSnippetForNumber + ")\"?$"
```

... and then, if the input matches regexForComposite, you use the two capturing groups to get the two numbers.  (Which you'd have to parse to get the numerical value.)

Hopefully that makes sense and can get you close enough to the finish line.  If you've never used Regexes before, I highly suggest you read up on them.  They're *incredibly* handy when you need to do string parsing that can otherwise be really annoying (like this exact problem!)